# Error running gae appcfg.sh with --severity parameter

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm trying  to deploy an application to google appengine with `appcfg.sh` tool.  But using parameter `--severity` the process fails.

```
appengine-java-sdk-1.9.15/bin/appcfg.sh --severity=0  update .
```

The output error is :

```
Encountered a problem: com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$UpdateAction cannot be cast to com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppCfg$RequestLogsAction Please see the logs [/tmp/appcfg5275118373648282055.log] for further information.
```

Could it be a bug in `appcfg.sh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `severity` switch is supplied when using the `request_logs` argument. Eg:

```
$ /path/to/appcfg.sh --severity=0 request_logs
```

To deploy in your case, you should use:

```
$ appengine-java-sdk-1.9.15/bin/appcfg.sh update .
```

More here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp